# Find a permutation that maximize the minimum of $\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}} + \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}$

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, np-hard

Consider a sequence of $n$ positive real numbers $a_0,\ldots,a_{n-1}$. Let $S_n$ be the set of permutations on $\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$.

We are interested to find

$$
\max_{\pi\in S_n}\left( \min_{i=0}^{n-1}\left( \frac{a_{\pi(i)}}{a_{\pi(i-1)}} + \frac{a_{\pi(i)}}{a_{\pi(i+1)}}\right)\right)
$$

The addition and subtraction in $\pi$ is under mod n.

It might be easier to consider the more general problem, where $b_0,\ldots,b_{n-1}$ is a sequence of positive real numbers.

$$
\max_{\pi\in S_n}\left( \min_{i=0}^{n-1}\left( a_{\pi(i)}(b_{\pi(i-1)}+b_{\pi(i+1)} )\right)\right)
$$

Is this problem $NP$-hard? I feel this problem is $NP$-Hard but I don't see any obvious reductions.

The greedy approach: sort the numbers, then insert them one by one into the list such that it maximizes the minimum of the sum of quotients. Turns out to be not optimal.

```
Greedy Smallest First
[5, 4, 4] 1.8
[5, 5, 4, 4] 1.8
[5, 5, 5, 4, 4] 1.8
[5, 9, 5, 5, 4, 4] 1.5555555555555556
Greedy: [5, 9, 5, 5, 4, 4] 1.5555555555555556
Best: [4, 5, 4, 5, 9, 5] 1.6

Greedy Largest First
[5, 22, 20] 0.4772727272727273
[4, 5, 22, 20] 1
[4, 4, 5, 22, 20] 1.2
[4, 3, 4, 5, 22, 20] 1.4772727272727273

Greedy: [4, 3, 4, 5, 22, 20] 1.4772727272727273
Best: [3, 4, 5, 20, 22, 4] 1.5
```

Comment: I *think* this might work: insert the elements successively (in sorted order) into a list so that the position $i$ maximises $\alpha(i)$ among all possible positions. ($\alpha(i)$ the sum of quotients)

Comment: I have found counterexample for the greedy approach